# How to get optional value while avoiding NoSuchElementException error?

Tags: java, string, java-8, java-stream, option-type

I have the following code

```
private static String getAddressLine(Addresses addresses) {
  if (addresses.getAddrCivicNo() == null || addresses.getStName() == null) 
    {
      return null;
    }

    StringBuilder addressLine = new StringBuilder("");

    addressLine.append(Optional.ofNullable(addresses.getAddrCivicNo()).get());
    addressLine.append(" ");
    addressLine.append(Optional.ofNullable(addresses.getAddrPreStrTypeDesignator()).get());
    addressLine.append(" ");
    addressLine.append(Optional.ofNullable(addresses.getStName()).get());
    addressLine.append(", ");
    addressLine.append(Optional.ofNullable(addresses.getAddrPostStrTypeDesignator()).get());
    addressLine.append(" ");
    addressLine.append(Optional.ofNullable(addresses.getAddrPostStrDirectionDesignator()).get());
    addressLine.append(" ");
    addressLine.append(Optional.ofNullable(addresses.getAddrPreStrDirectionDesignator()).get());
    addressLine.append(" ");
    addressLine.append(Optional.of(addresses.getAddrUnitDesignatorTypeCd()).get());
    addressLine.append(" ");
    addressLine.append(Optional.of(addresses.getAddrUnitNo()).get());

    return addressLine.toString();
}
```

If any of my fields are `null`, I get a `NoSuchElementException` error thanks to the `get()` call. If I remove the `get()` call I'm appending `Optional.empty`, but I would instead like to append nothing if the field is `null`. Any suggestions?

Comment: Why are you using `Optional` anyway? The values are wrapped into an `Optional` and then immediately unpacked again. What's the point of doing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also try to normalize those values. I don't think the `Optional` "monad" here is providing any value.

Something like this should work (only for `String` values):

```java
public static String nullToEmpty(final String str) {
  return (null == str) ? "" : str;
}

// ...

nullToEmpty(addresses.getAddrCivicNo());
```

Comment: Thanks, everyone for the help. Some very interesting solutions.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a default value, for example an empty `String`:

```
private static final String DEFAULT_FIELD = "";

Optional.ofNullable(addresses.getAddrCivicNo()).orElse(DEFAULT_FIELD)
```

Although checking for null and then resolving (possibly with `?:` operator) would be cleaner if there is no mapping of nullable value needed.

Answer (score 1):

if you're on JDK9+ I'd suggest looking into [Objects.requireNonNullElse](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#requireNonNullElse-T-T-) i.e.:

```
public static <T> T requireNonNullElse​(T obj,T defaultObj)
```

Which is much cleaner and more readable than doing `Optional.ofNullable(addresses.getAddrCivicNo()).orElse(...)` etc.  It's also more performance-friendly to use the former as you don't need to create an optional instance.

Further, some ideas to *potentially* simplify your logic.

you could use `Stream.of` and then filter the nulls out then join with the specified delimiter.

```
Stream.of(addresses.getAddrCivicNo(), addresses.getAddrPreStrTypeDesignator(), ...)
      .filter(Objects::nonNull)
      .collect(joining(" "));
```

Another suggestion I'd recommend you to consider is potentially having the function `getAddressLine` return a `Optional<String>` instead of `String`. This essentially enables the clients of this API to not deal with *nullity* and instead gives them the optional API to operate on which provides several useful methods to unwrap an Optional safely.

Comment: Unfortunately, we're still on Java 8. I really like your use of the Stream, very clean but the problem in my case is that some of my fields have a blank space separating them while other fields have a comma separation. Basically I'm building an address so it will look something like 1234 Street, City, Postal Code

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Objects.toString](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Objects.html#toString%28java.lang.Object,java.lang.String%29) method, which takes a ‘use if first argument is null’ argument:

```
addressLine.append(Objects.toString(addresses.getAddrCivicNo(), ""));
addressLine.append(" ");
addressLine.append(Objects.toString(addresses.getAddrPreStrTypeDesignator(), ""));
addressLine.append(" ");
addressLine.append(Objects.toString(addresses.getStName(), ""));
addressLine.append(", ");
addressLine.append(Objects.toString(addresses.getAddrPostStrTypeDesignator(), ""));
addressLine.append(" ");
addressLine.append(Objects.toString(addresses.getAddrPostStrDirectionDesignator(), ""));
addressLine.append(" ");
addressLine.append(Objects.toString(addresses.getAddrPreStrDirectionDesignator(), ""));
addressLine.append(" ");
addressLine.append(addresses.getAddrUnitDesignatorTypeCd());
addressLine.append(" ");
addressLine.append(addresses.getAddrUnitNo());
```